# PC connects to Samba Server automatically

Tags: linux, grub, samba, smb

This is a situation where the PC connects to Samba Server (SMB) automatically. I first realized this was happening on a Windows 8.1 laptop, which is a refurbished HP Pavilion g7 from HP. When booting using Kubuntu on USB, I then noticed in Network a Samba Server of 128 TiB (140 TB) in size.

A few days ago I borrowed someone else's laptop, a Toshiba running Windows 7. Everything seemed to run great for one day then once again a slew of problems with the PC. When I booted from Kubuntu using a USB drive, I noticed it was also connected to a Samba Server of the same size. In both cases it also shows a Loop Device.

Any ideas of how or why this exists? I have suspected unusual network traffic. Yesterday I downloaded Wireshark to learn how to analysis the traffic. Two hours later, my Wireshark starts up but the GUI is really messed up and the application is not functional. I did manage to get one short recording.

Looking through the file structure in Linux it doesn't appear to be a good thing, and it also seems it may be dual booting with Grub.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sure, how is my computer connecting to a Samba Server?